# JQuery creating divs and associated buttons on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating text fields each time a button is clicked, with each new `div` I create I also want to give it a button to delete this field. As can be seen in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o28qjeya/11/).

However the button associated with each newly created `div` doesn't delete it's associated field. How can this delete that text fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: If you do a quick search, you'll find many more duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use delegation.
This works for the elements new to the DOM, after it was already loaded.

```
$(document).on('click','.deleteButton',function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').hide();//remove
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o28qjeya/12/)

Note: I added `deleteButton` class to the dynamically inserted buttons.

Comment: Thanks. How could you clear down the values as well as hiding the fields to?

Comment: @user94628 Using `.remove()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can set in your button an `onclick` function and handle delete there like following:

```
window.deleteRow = function(obj){
    $(obj).parent().remove();
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o28qjeya/26/)